# google analytics goal - visit 2 pages not one after another on same site

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I am struggling with setting up a goal in GA. I have a goal page and another page X that I want to be a part of a funnel. It is not possible for visitor to go directly from page X to goal page. It can take any amount of time. For me ii is important to measure how many visitors that visited page X visited goal page as well.

As I understand funnel in GA - it is only a ordered list of pages one after another. 

I tried to setup a goal with url destination and funnel with one step but it seems that google thinks of this step as a page directly before the goal page. 
Can anybody point me to right solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you did it right. I will put down the steps I did in order to set the funnel. It worked for me. All you need to do is to:

1. Click Admin in the top right corner.
2. Choose Account and Property and click Goals.
3. Click Create a Goal
4. Choose Custom in the Goal setup and click Next Step
5. Fill in the name of your Goal and choose Destination option from the list and click Next step.
6. Goal details: 
   a) Fill in the URL of the goal page in the field Destination with Equals to
      chosen in the drop-down list. 
   b) Check Funnel option to be ON. 
   c) Set Step1 Name to "page X" and Screen/Page to the URL of "page X".
   d) I guess it's better for you to check Required? option to YES.
7. Create goal.

All is set now. If I understood your question well, my instructions should work. I tested the instructions on my website and it worked. 
You can do as many steps between "page X" and "goal page" as you wish. But it is necessary to make the steps during one visit.
In my experiment, I visited "Page X", then I visited 2 more websites, and then I visited "goal page". The goal was accomplished and it was visualized.

It took a few minutes for the funnel to be visualized in my analytics and show the goal accomplishment.

To get more information on this topic, I recommend KISSmetrics [Conversion Funnal Survival Guide](http://blog.kissmetrics.com/conversion-funnel-survival-guide/).